# Do clang sanitisers check for uninitialised memory?

Tags: c++, clang

I have a simple example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    unsigned long int a;
    
    printf("a = 0x%lx\n", a);

    return 0;
}
```

<kbd>[demo](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/82ddc90c9459c4c3)</kbd>

Clearly, this code has UB. But when I try to sanitise it with:

```
clang -fsanitize=undefined -O0 -xc main.cpp && ./a.out
```

it runs "fine". Is this behaviour expected? Should I be using another sanitiser for this?

**Update:**

- It [doesn't seem](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/63b0623e05fed865) to work for c++ too with `-fsanitize=memory`.
- And for dynamic allocations [as well](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ef97ebe22875e73f).

**Update:**

I understand that my example is trivial. And a good compiler could detect such issue. I just wrote a simple example to understand if the feature works at all. There is a wide range on uninitialised memory errors that cannot be detected by a compiler. For instance, if an uninitialised memory chunk was allocated in one `.cpp` and used in another `.cpp`.

Comment: You tagged this question wrong, as you build the code as C. And in C, unlike C++, it might not be UB to use indeterminate values. It depends on if the value is a *trap representation* for the type. However if you enable more warnings (e.g. `-Wall`) then you will get a warning about it.

Comment: I think you want [`-fsanitize=memory`](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/UsersManual.html#controlling-code-generation)

Comment: [Here](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/63b0623e05fed865) I compile it as C++ with `-fsanitize=memory`. The result is same unfortunately.

Comment: I appreciate that `-Wall` will find it. I just wanted to write a simple example that has an uninitialised variabe to try the tool.

Comment: There are lots of forms of undefined behaviour that cannot be readily detected.   Some cannot be detected by a compiler.  Others cannot be detected by static analysers.   Some only occur as a result of specific combinations of inputs at run time.   So it is not particularly surprising that some forms of undefined behaviour can be undetected by various tools.   Even if some forms are obvious to a programmer, bear in mind that the programmer uses a rather complicated neural net (aka their brain) to detect undefined behaviour, and automated tools use different techniques.

Comment: fyi detected by the compiler - https://godbolt.org/z/K4b9WP9b7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is that the standard library is not compiled with sanitiser enabled. And the uninitialised variable is referenced in `printf`. It's enough to read from this variable in the same function to trigger the sanitiser:

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    unsigned long int a;
    
    if (a == 42) {
        printf("a = 0x%lx\n", a);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

```
clang++ -fsanitize=memory -O0 main.cpp && ./a.out
```

```
==28857==WARNING: MemorySanitizer: use-of-uninitialized-value
    #0 0x494af6 in main (/tmp/1622902848.6385949/a.out+0x494af6)
    #1 0x7fefc72bc82f in __libc_start_main /build/glibc-Cl5G7W/glibc-2.23/csu/../csu/libc-start.c:291
    #2 0x419de8 in _start (/tmp/1622902848.6385949/a.out+0x419de8)

SUMMARY: MemorySanitizer: use-of-uninitialized-value (/tmp/1622902848.6385949/a.out+0x494af6) in main
Exiting
```

<kbd>[demo](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/221abfd56e9519a4)</kbd>

And yes, as @Alan Birtles noted, it needs `-fsanitize=memory`.

Comment: On the other hand, in [this example](https://godbolt.org/z/Wx5d44c3d) the uninitialized variable is passed to a different function which reads it, either by value or by reference, and the sanitizer doesn't notice, even though everything is compiled with the sanitizer.  So I don't think that having printf compiled with sanitizer is really the issue here.

Comment: @NateEldredge I think it's trying to track the origin of the uninitialised value. It'll start failing as soon as you use the global variable. Try to add `return z` to `main`.

Comment: Note also it's possible to [instrument libc++](https://github.com/google/sanitizers/wiki/MemorySanitizerLibcxxHowTo#instrumented-libc) for MSan, though `printf` is a libc function, so not sure if that's enough.

Comment: Actually, my answer may not be correct: [the documentation](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/MemorySanitizer.html) says that it intercepts libc functions to run the checks.